# Is it possible to iterate through a array in lambda expressions? (java)

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

I need to make a new `ForkJoinTask` for every division, and don't know how to get to the next position in the array. Can someone help me?

```
protected static double parManyTaskArraySum(final double[] input, final int numTasks) {

        double sum = 0;
        // ToDo: Start Calculation with help of ForkJoinPool
        ForkJoinPool fjp = new ForkJoinPool(numTasks);
        fjp.execute(() -> {

            sum+=( 1 / input[???] ); //the problem is here
        });

        return sum;
    }
```

> Exception: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

Comment: i don't see any loop. And the error message is about `sum`, which you cannot modify from the lambda, as the message states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding a `Runnable` lambda to your `ForkJoinPool`. 
As such, you cannot parametrize it with the desired array chunk.

You should actually define a class extending `RecursiveTask<Double>` whose constructor takes the array chunk as parameter, and decides whether to operate on the whole of it or fork if it's too large.

Then use the `invoke` method of your `ForkJoinPool` to get the result of the final calculation, by passing it a new instance of that `RecursiveTask<Double>` taking the whole array (the task will the decide based on your criteria whether to do everything in one go, or to fork, say, half of the array's elements to another task and join later).

**Note** as there is some confusion here.

If in fact, you *don't* need to leverage the fork/join framework and only want to perform your operation asynchronously, there are many ways to do so without a `ForkJoinPool`.

For instance:

```
Callable<Double> call  = () -> {return Arrays.stream(input).sum();};
Future<Double> future =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(call);
// when you're ready
Double sum = future.get();
```